# Hide custom post type from nav menu manager

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

Is it possible to hide or remove some custom post type from here?
[image: here are the screenshot]

Comment: Please have a look at ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far, where do you stumble, what does not work ?

Answer (score 4):

```
// set up the arguements for post type
$labels = array(....);
$args =
        array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true, // display on menu and site
            'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => false,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 111,
            'supports' =>
            array(
                'title'
            )
);
// register the post type
register_post_type(__('galery'), $args);
```

If the `'public' => true` is true, then a post type will appear in the menu and site.

If the `'public' => false` - hidden in the menu and site.

If you want to show on the site but hidden in the menu, there is a special option: `'show_in_nav_menus' => true`

Example:

```
$labels = array(....);
    $args =
            array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true, // display on menu and site
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false // hiden on menu
                'publicly_queryable' => false,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => false,
                'rewrite' => false,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'menu_position' => 111,
                'supports' =>
                array(
                    'title'
                )
    );
    // register the post type
    register_post_type(__('payout'), $args);
```

If you can not edit register_post_type You can Hide use css.
To click in the browser f12 and find id element:

[image]

in my case, to add to the styles admin:

```
    #add-kleo-nav-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

If there is a question how to add styles in admin area - ask.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: +1 for the CODE solution, however, hiding it using CSS in the admin panel is not a good idea. You have `Screen Options` for that. See my answer for the `screen option`.

Comment: I completely agree

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the custom post type correctly, hiding it should be easy.

First, from your your Admin Panel, go to:

```
Appearance -> Menus
```

Then, from there at the top right, you'll see `Screen Options` button. If you click that button, it'll show you the option to show & hide `Pages`, `Posts`, `Your Custom Post Type`, `Categories`, `Tags` etc. Like the following:

[image]

From there, show or hide as you need.

Comment: yes right ans :)